# drop database command is cancelled ^C

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to know what happens when a drop database command is canceled using `^C`.

Does it partially removes the data or completely?

Comment: I'm gonna try this today. Sounds fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try again, but with the correct statement ;)

When you cancel a query in psql, what it does internally is to send a `pg_cancel_backend()` to the server. This returns directly, but the statement might still be running on the server.

When a query is run, there are a few times it checks if it safely can cancel the statement, and in that case do so. This applies to a `drop database` statement as well.

There is a short time between the database files are removed from disk and the statement is committed where things can get interesting. It is not possible to cancel the query during that phase, but if there is a server crash then there is a risk that the database still exists in the meta tables, but the files are removed from disk.

*Update, clarification of when it can be cancelled*

When the server receives a cancel request, it marks a flag that the statement should be cancelled, and the statement checks that flag once in a while during execution. To explain what happens when we cancel the `drop database` we need to understand what it does:

1. Statement is received from the server.
2. Implicit transaction is started.
3. Lock is taken on the database.
4. Checks are made to make sure that the database is not being used.
5. The database is removed from the meta tables.
6. A checkpoint is written in the WAL.
7. The database files are removed.
8. The transaction is committed.

At any point up until #6 the statement can be cancelled (the final check of the flag is done at #6)

Comment: `create database` can't be run inside a transaction block

Comment: gah, you're right. I should not answer when tired, read it as drop table.

Comment: I tested it on a database and canceled it as soon as I issue the command `drop database db_name`. The database is still there.

Comment: Yes, because then you managed to cancel it before it doesn't accept cancellations. It does a lot of stuff before that happens, which is usually quite fast, so if you wait a little bit between the execution and the cancellation it should still continue. Granted, my answer isn't very clear in that. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: ok, I actually missed one place where it can be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what happens when a drop database command is canceled using `^C.` Does it partially removes the data or completely?

That depends on why the command is hanging. `DROP DATABASE` does a lot of stuff to get the locks it needs and to ensure no one else is connected and the like. If stuck at a step [north of line 898](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/322548a8abe225f2cfd6a48e07b99e2711d28ef7/src/backend/commands/dbcommands.c#L898), nothing happens.

If you move past that though you could be in a world of fun. My assumption is that the `DROP` stuff happens in milliseconds.

The database files are removed with `remove_dbtablespaces`. That runs (almost) last so the database is already gone at that point. It's just cleaning up the file system.

Comment: Not necessarily, the statement is still running under its own implicit transaction, so if something would happen to the server between the remove_tablespaces and the commit the server would rollback the changes during next recovery but the files would be missing. This should not happen short of a server crash, but it can happen. Anything that happens in the drop statement is recoverable except for the removal of the files.